# Convert ellipsoid height to geoid using SpatiaLite

Tags: sql, spatialite, ellipsoid, geoid

I would like to convert ellipsoid height to geoid (EGM2008) using SpatiaLite. is there any query that we could achieve this?

Comment: I think that must have [libspatialite 5 built on PROJ.6](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=PROJ.6), the [egm08_25.gtx](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj-datumgrid/blob/master/world/egm08_25.gtx) grid file in the `PROJ_LIB` path, and just transform a PointZ to Srid 3855. I don't know how to make the first requirement

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca good point thank. I have to take a look at this